# Why does 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

```
vif["vif_values"] = [variance_inflation_factor(cancer_x_pca1_df.values, i) for i in range(cancer_x_pca1_df)]
```

### Error is :

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 #vif["vif_values"] = [variance_inflation_factor(cancer_x_pca1_df.values, i) for i in
>   range(cancer_x_pca_df_shape1)]
>   ----> 2 vif["vif_values"] = [variance_inflation_factor(cancer_x_pca1_df.values, i) for i in
>   range(cancer_x_pca1_df,0)]
>         3 vif["Variables"]  = cancer_x_pca1_df.columns
>
> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 2):

Because a range has to be integers, and you are telling it that a dataframe is a range.  I had this problem last week.  Just change it from

```
for i in range(cancer_x_pca1_df)]
```

To

for i in range(len(cancer_x_pca1_df))]

Or you might be able to just do

for i in (cancer_x_pca1_df)]